# Nextflow config file for cpus setting

Tags: nextflow

I am confused about the Nextflow config cups setting, is this cpus number the actual CPU number or thread number?

```
process {

    executor = 'local'

    cpus = 24
    memory = 128.GB
    time = 6.h

    withName: CENTRIFUGE {
        cpus = 32
        memory = 384.GB
        time = 3.h
    }
}
```

Does this setting means, no mater how many parallel jobs are running, the system would never exceed this setting? Or do I have to set the parallelization number in a resources exhausting process?

```
def barcodes = (1..20).collect { String.format("barcode%02d", it) }
params.infq = barcodes.collect { "../fastq_pass/$it/*.fastq.gz" }
params.outdir = "Analysis"
params.hostref = "/mnt/genomic.fna"
params.targetref = "/mnt/NTM.fasta"
params.db = "/mnt/db"

process CAT {
    debug true
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/orifq", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(bc), path(fq)

    output:
    path "${bc}.fastq.gz"

    """
    cat ${fq} > ${bc}.fastq.gz
    """
}

process ALL_STATS {
    debug true
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/stats", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path orifq

    output:
    path "all_stats.txt"

    """
    seqkit stat ${orifq} -T > all_stats.txt
    """
}

process NanoLyse {
    debug true
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/outfq", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path orifq

    output:
    path "${orifq.getSimpleName()}_reads_without_host.fastq.gz"

    """
    gunzip -c ${orifq} | NanoLyse --reference ${params.hostref} | gzip > ${orifq.getSimpleName()}_reads_without_host.fastq.gz
    """
}

process CENTRIFUGE {
    debug true
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/centrifuge", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path filterfq
    path params.db

    output:
    path "${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_cenout.csv"
    path "${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_report.tsv"
    path "${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_cenout.kraken"

    """
    centrifuge -x ${params.db} -U ${filterfq} -S ${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_cenout.csv --report-file ${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_report.tsv
    centrifuge-kreport -x ${params.db} ${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_cenout.csv > ${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_cenout.kraken
    """
}

process NO_HOST_STATS {
    debug true
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/stats", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path filterfq

    output:
    path "no_host_stats.txt"

    """
    seqkit stat ${filterfq} -T > no_host_stats.txt
    """
}

process MAPPING {
    debug true
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/bam", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path filterfq

    output:
    path ("${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_no_host.bam"), emit: bam
    path ("${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_no_host.bam.bai")

    """
    minimap2 -ax map-ont ${params.targetref} ${filterfq} | samtools view -b | samtools sort > ${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_no_host.bam
    samtools index ${filterfq.getSimpleName()}_no_host.bam
    """
}

process EXTRACT_MAPPED {
    debug true
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/outfq", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path bam

    output:
    path "${bam.getBaseName()}_mapped.fastq.gz"

    """
    samtools fastq -F 0X904 ${bam} | gzip > ${bam.getBaseName()}_mapped.fastq.gz
    """
}

process MAPPED_STATS {
    debug true
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/stats", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path mappedfq

    output:
    path "mapped_stats.txt"

    """
    seqkit stat ${mappedfq} -T > mapped_stats.txt
    """
}


process STATS_SUMMARY {
    debug true
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/stats", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path "${projectDir}/Analysis/stats/all_stats.txt"
    path "${projectDir}/Analysis/stats/no_host_stats.txt"
    path "${projectDir}/Analysis/stats/mapped_stats.txt"

    output:
    path "Summary.csv"

    """
    python ${projectDir}/summ.py     ${projectDir}/Analysis/stats/all_stats.txt ${projectDir}/Analysis/stats/no_host_stats.txt {projectDir}/Analysis/stats/mapped_stats.txt
    """
}

workflow {
    Channel
    .fromPath(params.infq, checkIfExists: true)
    .map { it -> [it.name.split("_")[2], it] }
    .groupTuple()
    .set{infq_ch}

    CAT(infq_ch) \
    |collect \
    |ALL_STATS

    NanoLyse(CAT.out) \
    |collect \
    |NO_HOST_STATS

    CENTRIFUGE(NanoLyse.out, params.db)

    MAPPING(NanoLyse.out)

    EXTRACT_MAPPED(MAPPING.out.bam) \
    |collect \
    |MAPPED_STATS

    STATS_SUMMARY(ALL_STATS.out, NO_HOST_STATS.out, MAPPED_STATS.out)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`cpus`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#cpus) directive just lets you set the number of CPUs in your resource request. It is then up to your job scheduler to fulfill this request. Note that this is just a *request* and not all resource managers will impose CPU or memory limits. This means that it is ultimately your responsibility to ensure that your jobs do not use more (or much less) than what you ask for. Using more than what you ask for, for example, can potentially over-subscribe the node(s) that your jobs land on. To use the number of CPUs defined using the `cpus` directive, we can use the [`task.cpus`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#process-implicit-variables) implicit variable in our script block, for example:

```
params.seqs = '/path/to/seqs/*.fa'

process blastp {

    input:
    path input_sequence

    """
    blastp \\
        -num_threads ${task.cpus} \\
        -query input_sequence

    """
}

workflow {

    seqs = Channel.fromPath( params.seqs )

    blastp( seqs )
}
```

And override any defaults using one or more [process selectors](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#process-selectors) in your nextflow.config:

```
process {

    executor = 'local'

    cpus = 2
    memory = 128.GB
    time = 6.h

    withName: blastp {
        cpus = 8
        memory = 12.GB
        time = 1.h
    }
}
```

If I was to run the above workflow on my local workstation which has an octa-core Xeon processor, Nextflow will run only one job at a time. I believe an exception is raised if you try to ask for more CPU or memory than what your system has installed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now I know the cups setting defines the core number of the cup not the thread. 

But I am still confused about the parallelization of the process. I ran a workflow that parallel up to 20 jobs in a single process without any setting for the resources and it crashed the server (4 octa-core Xeon processor and 504GB memories ), so I have to make sure that the setting is adequate for the workflow and most of all not to crash the server.

Comment: My understanding:

1. The document you shared explains the priority of selector: withName>withLabel>specified in workflow script>generic configuration. So based on your example, to ensure the setting is applied I should used withName selector rather than ${task.cups}

2. If the maximum CPUs and memories resources in the system are set in any of the settings, Nextflow will only use the value set, based on the selector priority, and control how many jobs can be executed in parallel.

Comment: So my question is, would Nextflow behave the same if only half of the resources were set?
Let’s us your example, but with our server resources, (4 octa-core Xeon processor and 504GB memories): with the setting cups =8 for blastp process, would Nextflow only run one job or would it execute up to 4 jobs parallelly or even beyond and crash the server?

Comment: @Hanjié Usually when we talk about how many CPUs a server has, we're actually talking about a total thread count. For example, what is the output of `grep -c "^processor" /proc/cpuinfo`? If your Xeons are Hyper-Threading enabled, I'd expect your server to have 64 CPUs available. You should then be able to run up to 8 blastp jobs concurrently given the configuration above. If you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76603283/edit) your question to include your workflow details, I'd be happy to take a look and offer some suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Steve, the workflow details is added.

Comment: No worries @Hanjié, would you also be able to paste your `nextflow.config`? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Steve, I didn't have a Nextflow.config in the first place, and after crashing the server, I have to make sure my workflow won't do that again. Based on that run, all processes ran just fine except for the CENTRIFUGE process, that's where the system crashed. So I used your example and updated the configuration part in my question. Thanks

Comment: Also I found the setting on https://nf-co.re/docs/usage/configuration I am intrigued by the --max_cpus, --max_memory and --max_time setting but still trying to figure out how it is done.

Comment: @Hanjié I think without specifying the `cpus` or `memory` directives (either within your workflow script or in your nextflow.config file), Nextflow won't reserve the required resources to run your jobs. I'm not familiar with `centrifuge`, but from the docs it looks like it defaults to using just one thread: https://github.com/DaehwanKimLab/centrifuge/blob/master/MANUAL.markdown#centrifuge-options-p. So I would not expect it to require 32 CPUs and 384 GB of memory. In any case, I think using `-p {task.cpus}` should be enough to control it.

Comment: @Hanjié I'm not sure if CENTRIFUGE is the problem. It might indeed be (I have no experience with this tool), but I suspect the problem is more likely the shear number of jobs running with unlimited resources: `params.infq = barcodes.collect { "../fastq_pass/$it/*.fastq.gz" }`. To avoid problems, I would start by updating your workflow script (or preferably your `nextflow.config`) with what resources you think each process will use (using the `withName` process selectors like in the example) and then, with a small set of test files, closely monitor the resource usage of each process.

Comment: @Hanjié You can also use the [`-with-report`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/tracing.html#execution-report) option to produce an execution report if you're not already. This will produce statistics for CPU and RSS. I wouldn't be too worried about `--max_cpus` and `--max_memory` at this stage. These params just let the user set maximum values for the `cpus` and `memory` directives, respectively.